# rsync --exclude-from option won't ignore directories with spaces

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm having a hard time making an `--exclude-from=` file correctly exclude directories with spaces with rsync (v3.0.9 from macports).

Trying to ignore a folder named `Adele - 21 [2011] flac/`

Tried :

```
- Adele - 21 [2011] flac/
- "Adele - 21 [2011] flac/"
- "Adele\ -\ 21\ [2011]\ flac/"
- 'Adele - 21 [2011] flac/'
- 'Adele\ -\ 21\ [2011]\ flac/'
```

Tried `-s` switch.

Still not working...

---

EDIT : what the hell! This seems to be working :

```
- Adele - 21 \[2011\] flac/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the parameter for `--exclude` is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

This means `Adele - 21 [2011] flac` matches `Adele - 21` followed by one of `[012]` followed by `flac`

To fix this, you need to escape the special characters `[` and `]`